# May I know how to find Time frequency power spectrogram of a signal?

Tags: frequency, eeg

I am analyzing EEG signal and I am unable to understand the term Time-Frequency Power Spectrogram. Please Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some signals (those stationary enough) can better explained, or described, through a Fourier transform. Since it is energy preserving, one usually uses the **power spectral density**, or "the squared Fourier spectrum".

EEGs can be stationary over local time frames. Hence, time-Frequency power spectrograms are just **power spectral densities** computed on sliding overlapping windows.

Comment: Ya I found it to be Power Spectral Densities, Thanks a lot sir

Comment: And would you evaluate the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

## Short-time Fourier transform

Traditional Fourier analysis provides no information about evolution of frequency components over time. However, Short-time Fourier transform (STFT), a method which applies a short-time window to the signal and performs a series of Fourier transforms within this window as it slides across all the data, can overcome this limitation, providing a time–frequency representation of the signal.

In MATLAB, try

```
doc spectrogram
```

## Continuous Wavelet Transform

Alternatively, continuous wavelet transforms (CWT) provide a useful approach in investigating non-stationary signals, this is often regarded as an “optimal” solution with regard to time and frequency resolution. Reportedly, CWT perform better at detecting abrupt changes in non-stationary signals compared to STFT.

In MATLAB, try

```
doc cwt
```

Generally, EEG signals have a low signal to noise ratio (SNR), therefore it is preferred to use ensemble averaging over trials for your time-frequency analysis (TFA), should the study design allow it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It was halpful